# Calculating orders placed on the end of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently studying SQL Server using the book Ben-Gan, Itzik. T-SQL Fundamentals. Below is a query used to select order placed at end of the month. (I know that function EOMONTH() can also be used)

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid 
FROM Sales.Orders  
WHERE orderdate = DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, '18991231', orderdate), '18991231');
```

The author's explanation is:

> This expression first calculates the difference in terms of whole
>   months between an anchor last day of some month (December 31, 1899, in
>   this case) and the specified date. Call this difference diff. By
>   adding diff months to the anchor date, you get the last day of the
>   target month.

However, I'm still a bit confused as to how it actually works. Would someone kindly explain it?

Comment: When you get deeper into the reporting aspects of databases you discover data warehouses. Then you discover this thing called a calendar table which is another approach to this problem: create a table listing every day ever along with every useful attribute of that date, including what the last day of the month is. Since you're studying SQL Server, it's enlightening for you to see two completely different (but both completely valid) approaches to solving the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a rather arcane way to do this.  What the code is doing is calculating the number of months since the last day of some month.  Then, it adds this number of months to that date.  Because of the rules of `dateadd()`, the month remains the last date.

However, I prefer a simpler method:

```
where day(dateadd(day, 1, orderdate)) = 1
```

I find this much clearer.

Comment: @GordenLinoff, thx for answer, it does seem to be a lot easier to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20160131', '20160201')
```

give us 1 month and

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '20160131')
```

give us    2016-02-29 00:00:00.000

that's ok

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the query myself and seem to have got the hang of it. here is what i wrote just in case anyone else is interested

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20160131', '20160201'), '20160131');
```

result:

```
2016-02-29 00:00:00.000
```

so my interpretation is that adding one or more "month" to a particular date in which the last date of the month is 31 will always return a date in which the date is the last day of the month. if this sentence makes any sense...

Answer (score 0):

If `orderdate` is a DATETIME field:

```
WHERE EOMONTH(orderdate) = CAST(orderdate as date)
```

If `orderdate` is **not** a DATETIME field:

```
WHERE EOMONTH(orderdate) = orderdate
```

Comment: The OP did mention that he knows about EOMONTH function, so I'm not sure whether your answer helps him at all.